# jQuery autonumeric mNum doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have a strange issue and I can't figure it out.

I use autoNumeric library on jQuery and I made a configuration like:

```
var inputConfig = {aSep : formatSeparator, aDec:formatDecimalSeparator, mDec:2};

    $(element).autoNumeric(inputConfig);
```

on a input field. So far, so good.

But I would like to add mNum on this configuration but this config isn't reconized.  I tried something like this:

```
var inputConfig = {aSep : formatSeparator, aDec:formatDecimalSeparator, mDec:2, mNum:3};

$(element).autoNumeric(inputConfig);
```

One think to notice is probably the fact that I use IE8 :-s (if thats matter). Any ideas?

Comment: What's `mNum`? It never mentioned in the plugin' [docs](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/).

Comment: Of course it is. http://prgassist.blogspot.de/2011/04/jquery-plugin-autonumeric.html

Comment: at the and ...thanks to @raina77ow I handle it with vMax: '999.99'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you found a solution, would you mind posting it as an answer so others can easily see what you did?

Comment: I wrote just above your answer what I did. I used vMax to set the max number you can enter in input. To post something what is already wrote it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but the answer is still valid.

In short, `mNum` has been deprecated for a long time now.

If you want to specify the number of decimal places, you have to define it via `vMax` or `vMin` (ie. `99999999.99` means you'll have 2 decimal places, while `99999999.9999` means you'll have 4), or you can override the `vMax` and `vMin` values with the `mDec` option (ie. `mDec : 5` to get 5 decimal places, no matter what the value of the minimum and maximum value are).

Please note that those option name are valid until the old v1.9.46 release.

If you are using the `2.0-betaX` version, be sure to use the more explicit option names :

```
`mDec` -> `decimalPlacesOverride`
`vMax` -> `maximumValue`
`vMin` -> `minimumValue`
```